# Random date shown in view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date

Why is there suddenly some random value in my view when I try to use        `<td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($object->date_expiry)) }} </td>`. In my database, my date is NULL but in my view it show the date 01-01-1970 even though it suppose to be blank. Is this a bug or something?

View.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
<table class="table">
        <tr>
        <th>Date Expiry</th>
        <td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($object->date_expiry)) }} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
        public function gettestInfo($id) {

  $data = test::where('id',$id)->get();

 return view('view',compact('data'));
}
```

dd($data) results:

```
#original: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "name" => "test3"
        "date_expiry" => null
        "created_at" => "2017-12-01 01:22:10"
        "updated_at" => "2017-12-01 01:22:10"
      ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the datetime will take the first init date which is 01-01-1970 if it null..

explanation :

> January 1, 1970 is the so called Unix epoch. It's the date where they
>   started counting the Unix time. If you get this date as a return
>   value, it usually means that the conversion of your date to the Unix
>   timestamp returned a (near-) zero result. So the date conversion
>   doesn't succeed. Most likely because it receives a wrong input.

do this instead

```
{{ ($object->date_expiry) ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($object->date_expiry)) : null }}
```

it will check if `$object->date_expiry` is have value.. it do the date function, else return `null`

**EDIT**

if you want to do if else statement

```
<td>
    @if($object->date_expiry == something else)
       {{ $object->date_expiry }}
    @elseif($object->date_expiry == something else)
       {{ // code }} 
    @endif
</td>
```

Comment: So it something like a if else statement in this case? And this work thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you so much for the clear explanation as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are converting a date that is has null value.
try this one.

```
{{ ($object->date_expiry) ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($object->date_expiry)) : null }}
```

Comment: thank you for replying ZeroOne has already explained to me already :)